# check if label exists in neo4j using python

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j

I'm using Neo4j via Python and I want to check if labels exist before creating new one because:
I used this but it doesn't work:

```
def delete_nodes(graph,label):
    if label.exists:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

I'm new in Neo4j. Thank you

Comment: Are you using py2neo or the official neo4j Python driver? If you use py2neo, which version?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got solution for my problem

Comment: Please share your solution

Comment: I used **graph.exists(node)**  which returns true or false. 
It's implemented in file **types.py**